# printing the last half of a string

Tags: javascript, string

Hi I'm trying to learn npm by working with read-line sync. I'm still pretty new to javascript and I'm trying to take the story var and print out just the last half of the string. I thought about maybe I could do it with slice but I don't know how to get it to print out the last half.

I also thought maybe I could write a function but again I not to sure how to get the last half of what ever is put in without hard coding an index. oh and can I write in functions in read-line sync? Thanks for the help.

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');

var firstNamer = readlineSync.question('Hi!, May I have your first 
name?');
console.log("Hi " + firstNamer.toUpperCase() + "! \nIt's sooooo good to 
see you");

var lastName = readlineSync.question("What's your last name?");
console.log(firstNamer.toUpperCase() + " " + lastName.toUpperCase() + " 
Wow! such a cool name.");

var age = readlineSync.question(`Now that I know your name is 
${firstNamer} ${lastName} \n can I get your age?`);
console.log(`WOW! \tNow I know that ${firstNamer.toUpperCase()} 
${lastName.toUpperCase()} is ${age} and that's just great!`);

var story = readlineSync.question(`Well ${firstNamer} now that I know 
your first and last name, tell me your story?`);
console.log(`So your telling me that that you ${story} hmmmm 
interesting`)

var halfStory = readlineSync.question(`So now that I know your story I 
can tell you that what you told me was ${story.length} characters long 
\n I'll show the last half now. ok?`);
console.log(`\n this is the last half of your story "${story.slice(0, 
story.length / 2)}"`);
```

Comment: _ust the last half of the string_ can you add a sample output ?

Comment: Try to read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp). JavaScript has severam String methods, and every string has a length property.

Comment: @desoares do you know if I can write a function into readline? like I said I'm still pretty new so I'm still trying to figure all this stuff out. I think I know how I can use the substring method. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use javascript's substring function, putting in the string length divided by 2 as the start position.

```
var x = "hello there!"
console.log(x.substring(x.length / 2))  // there!
```